# Android Face recognition and fingerprint authentication offline SDK

Tags: face-detection, fingerprint, face-recognition, android-fingerprint-api

I am looking to develop face a recognition and fingerprint authentication based attendance Android Application. I need face recognition SDK and fingerprint SDK with offline support too. Please help me If you know any third party or native SDK provider.

Answer (score 1):

If it's for Android, you have multiples possibilities:

- https://www.crossmatch.com/
- https://www.neurotechnology.com/
- https://www.innovatrics.com/

Regarding fingerprint, you cannot use embedded fingerprint reader on Android device, you need an external USB fingerprint reader.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Trueface.ai](https://trueface.ai/). They offer a low footprint offline SDK that can be used cross platform (including on Android).

Disclaimer: I work at Trueface.